# What type of memory should I use in a temperature datalogger with battery?

Tags: battery-operated, datalogger

I'm designing a temperature data logger that will operate with a CR2032 battery, but I'm unsure what storage device would be good to use in this application. I would like to have capacities greater than or equal to 64Mbits. Additionally, the main MCU will save data every 1, 2, 5, 10, or 30 minutes, which implies frequent writes to the storage device. Furthermore, it should withstand temperatures as low as -30°C and as high as 70°C. I was thinking of using NAND Flash memories, but I'm not sure what would be best.

Comment: [Everspin](https://www.everspin.com/parallel-interface-mram) makes some MRAM that may just fit. They can easily work at the voltages you'll be using with a CR2032 and are available with \$-40^\circ\text{C}\$ to \$+125^\circ\text{C}\$ specs, as well. 64 Mbit is just at the limit of their reach, right now. But at least it is reached. You should also look into FeRAM/FRAM. Those come in larger sizes. Both technologies are very low power. I only mention these because I have some of each and am exploring them for teaching CPU design here.

Comment: The MRAM also come in [serial interface](https://www.everspin.com/serial-peripheral-interface). I didn't mean to only point you to the parallel interface page. They make both kinds. But only the parallel supports 64 Mbit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider a high grade industrial SD card if that suits the design. The draw back is adding the cost of the SD card holder, but they are removable which might be nice for your customers. Since you probably don't need a high speed card due to your bandwidth, SD cards would be price competitive vs eMMC.